# Executing same child package parallely inside ForEach Loop from parent package in SSIS

Tags: asynchronous, ssis, parent-child, parallel.foreach, foreach-loop-container

I have parent package designed in such a way that
step 1: Data flow task fetches the list of configuration from db and stores in recordset.
step 2: for each loop having child package being called with it's project parameters set with values from previous task.

Now the scenario: if I get 2 records from step 1 then step 2 executes 2 times sequentially. How to execute the step 2 parallely for 2 configurations fetched from step1.

After googling for some amount of time, I copied child  execute package task 2 times inside for each loop but the values assignment from previous task to child package parameter is not mapping correctly. Please advise what I am doing incorrectly

Note: I am looking for workaround on Execute package task which calls the copies of child package inside for each loop of parent package to run asynchronously. The child package is generic and requires parameter binding where variable values from parent package is assigned to child package parameter values.So, each copy of child package should be able to fetch different variable value from the list and do parameter binding. Please let me know if this is possible.
[Execute package task parameter bindings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyCiY.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for link. Ihave edited the question to be more precise I am looking for having a solution in designing the parent package to have parallel execution of child package. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your foreach loop add an execute SQL and add this code and fill the correct info and parameters...

```
DECLARE @execution_id BIGINT
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] 
    @package_name=N'Package1.dtsx'
    , @project_name=N'Project1'
    , @folder_name=N'Folder1'
    , @use32bitruntime=False
    , @reference_id=NULL
    , @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT

-- Execute the package
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
```

This will kick off the package and NOT wait.

If you have package parameters to set, add this (between create and start) foreach one:

```
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
    @execution_id
    , @object_type = 30                     -- package parameter
    , @parameter_name = N'ParameterName'
    , @parameter_value = 1
```

Comment: I just have one doubt here, pardon me if this is silliest doubt I am asking on forum. The above code mentions about ssisdb catalog deployed packages but I have the package designed locally in visual studio and want to check the parallel processing testing before deployment to sql server. I was looking for some workaround on Execute package task where we have parameter bindings from parent to child.how better I could design so that inside for each loop, child package copies runs asynchronously. Appreciate your patience. Thank you.

Comment: Your child package needs to be deployed to SSISDB to work like this. AND exec package object does not run async

Comment: You bind the parameters with that last bit of sql. This is the only way i know to run your children async

Comment: I followed as per your suggestion and tested the package in ssms using TSQL but when I try to run execute sql task in Visual studio with database connection provided(sql server authentication) I am getting error of not executing TSQL commands using sql server authentication.Any workaround for this?

Comment: Thanks Keith. Your answer helped me a lot. I was having issues with parameter mapping in execute sql task,I changed from OLEDB to ADO.NET connection and resolved the issue today and finally test the solution for parallel processing.Thanks again for your time and information.

Comment: My guess is that the issue was parameter mapping. with OleDb vs ado